# Derive class A from a template class Base<A> so that Base<A> can use A::B?

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
private:
    typename T::B c;
};

class A : public Base<A>
{
public:
    class B;
};
```

Is something like this even possible? VC++ 2013 says B is not a member of A.

Comment: You can't, and GCC's error is more descriptive as for why http://ideone.com/90siYB

Comment: Which classes can you modify to introduce a workaround?

Comment: In your actual code, is B a type or a member variable?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, type, just like in the example.

Comment: And what's the goal you're trying to accomplish here?  I mean at a higher level, since what you've got here doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, the example does not reflect it, but it was an addition idea for the pimpl idiom. It would have secured m_impl (B) in a way that A can only ask for it via calling functions 'const B& impl() const' and 'B& impl()'. Just to prevent a non-const B function from being called from a const A function (possible because m_impl would be a pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go like this ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ee35cb783bf118c)):

```
template<typename T> struct Impl;
template<typename T> struct Nested;

template <typename T>
class Base
{
private:
    typename Nested<T>::type c;
};

struct A;

template<> struct Impl<A>   { class B { }; };
template<> struct Nested<A> { using type = typename Impl<A>::B; };

struct A : Base<A>, Impl<A>
{
    //...
};
```

Here, class `Impl` contains the part of `A` that does not depend on the `Base`, that is, the nested class `B`. Hence `A` now derives both `Base<A>` and `Impl<A>`.

Class `Nested` only contains an alias specifying the type of the above nested class. Now `Base` reads this type from `Nested` and defines its data member, of this type.

We need to declare `A` before we specialize `Impl` and `Nested` for it. And we need those specializations before defining `A` because at that point `Base<A>` is instantiated, and this requires that `Nested<A>` is complete, which in turn requires that `Impl<A>` is complete.

The main difference from [Philip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22610654/2644390) is that responsibilities are more separated:

- `Base` does not derive anything, so has less chance of being polluted. We only change the type of its data member to `typename Nested<T>::type`, that's it.
- `Nested` is a pure type trait. It only defines alias `type`, that's it.
- `Impl` is an implementation class. It contains the definition of nested class `B` or possibly anything else that does not depend on `Base`.

---

By the way, Stroustrup's 4th edition of [The C++ Programming Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) has the following code on page 771:

```
template<typename N>
struct Node_base : N::balance_type { };

template<typename Val, typename Balance>
struct Search_node : Node_base<Search_node<Val, Balance> >
{
    using balance_type = Balance;
};
```

which has exactly the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll digest this, advanced template programming is a distant topic for me.

Answer (score 6):

**THE STORY**

As stated in the comments directly on your question what you are trying to accomplish simply isn't possible since it's illegal to refer to an *incomplete type* (which `T = A` is inside `Base`).

---

**THE WORKAROUND**

The common workaround in cases of CRTP is to use a `trait` to denote members that should be available in both `Derived` and `Base`, but which are not meant to be declared/defined in `Base`.

Even though this isn't really equivalent of what you are trying to accomplish it is very close to it, and follow somewhat equivalent semantics.

```
template<class> struct some_trait;       // primary template

template <class T>
struct A : some_trait<T> {               // (1)
  typename some_trait<T>::C a;
};

template<> struct some_trait<struct B> { // (2)
  class C { };
};

struct B : A<B> {                        // (3)
  C b;
};
```

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  B a; // legal
}
```

---

**WHY DOES THE WORKAROUND... WORK?**

To cut it short; we are no longer trying to access the internals of an *incomplete type*.

`some_trait<B>` is a complete type directly after it's definition (ie. the specialization) marked `(2)`, and because of this it can be used by `(1)` and `(3)` without causing any issues.

Comment: This [won't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9cc460456d07316). You need `using C = typename some_trait<T>::C;` in `A`.

Comment: Plus, struct `B` now has *two* data members of type `C`.

Comment: @iavr I actually didn't try to compile the snippet before posting, stupid mistake, I will change it to make it 100% legal.

Comment: @iavr as a note; the only thing that requires changes is what is in `template<class> struct A`, see the edited post. [coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6e0570e9baf84ab). `B` has two data members of type `C` to show that `C` is available both in `B` and it's base (through the trait).